# How to create multiple Futures (threads) using a collection iterator in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, future

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
val colFutures = (0 to bcConfig.receiverThreads).map { llCollectors.filter(_.enabled).map { 
    llcRecord => 
        Future {
            ActOnRecord(llcRecord)
        }
    }
}
```

But this fails with:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

(probably because I'm trying to traverse the llCollectors using an iterator that can only be used once?)

If I remove the `(0 to bcConfig.receiverThreads).map {}` part it works fine but, of course, only one thread is created per record in `llCollectors`, however, I'd like to create multiple Futures (threads) per record in `llCollectors`.

As I'm Scala newbie I'm looking for advice on how to accomplish this.

Comment: FYI, futures are not threads. Futures run on threads but there is not a 1:1 correlation.  A new thread is not created per future.

Comment: There should be no problem with "using an iterator" in this way. Check the line number given in the exception traceback - are you sure this is the code that's failing?